# A vector calculus formula

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $A, B$ be vector fields in $\mathbb R^3$. We have
$$
\text{curl}\bigl((A\cdot \nabla)B\bigr)=(A\cdot \nabla)\text{curl}B
-((\text{curl}A)\cdot \nabla)B+R(A,B).
$$
I know that $R(A,A)=0$ and I guess that $R$ should resemble to 
$$
d a_j\wedge
d b_j
=\text{curl} A \ \times \text{curl} B+\text{div} A\ \text{curl} B
-\text{div} B\ \text{curl} A.$$
Is there a simple closed form for $R(A,B)$?

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [A vector calculus formula](https://mathoverflow.net/q/330032). [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice regarding [meta-tag:cross-posting].